# How to sort a SAS table in a customized order ?

Tags: sas

I have a SAS table

```
Name     id   .....
Mary     3
Melissa  5
Alan     6
Greg     7
..
```

I want to sort this table in a special order : `Alan, Melissa, Greg, Mary . . .` 
This is neigher alphabetic, nor numeric. This is the way I need the records to show up in the table. How can I do this ?

I know one way around : I create an personID : `1 to whatever` based on my preference, then sort by that `personID` . Is there any direct way to specify the order ?

Comment: That is the only solution I can think of. The other way which is not a sort would be to create 4 datasets using a where statement (where name = 'Mary') etc and set these together in the desired order to create one dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some method for telling SAS how to sort.  How would you communicate that to a human being?

There is the ability to create custom translation tables, with `PROC TRANTAB`, though that would operate at the character level if I understand.  You also have quite a few capabilities in `PROC SORT` with `SORTSEQ=LINGUISTIC`.  Those won't solve your specified problem above, but if your problem is more nuanced than described it might be the right solution.

The only way to solve your specific problem without creating a new variable is probably to use a format.  You can create a format where the values (1,2,3,4) are labled ("ALAN" "MELISSA" "GREG" "MARY"). Then sort on that.  It will still display correctly but it will sort as you request.  This is the SAS version of creating a factor in R, basically.

Comment: Right . . format . This is I guest the best option. Thanks